# How to go to the bottom of a ListView without scrolling?

Tags: android, listview

I know how to scroll all the way down to the last item, but I am trying to go to the bottom of the list with out the scroll animation.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)

Comment: listView.setSelection(index) will work

Comment: Are you looking for setScrollX(int) or setScrollY(int) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ListView 
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
...
></ListView>
```

or `listView.setSelection(value)`

This one ?

Answer (score 1):

You can go on any element like this
YourListView.setSelectionFromTop(PositionYouwanttosee, 0);
Call this method after setting your listView adapter